# How to reflect field policy's read function return types in graphql-codegen?

Tags: typescript, react-apollo, graphql-codegen

Assume this type policy:

```
// TLDR enum field of User object is replaced with some class instance on read
const userTypePolicies = {
  User: {
    fields: {
      status: {
        read: (value: STATUS_ENUM) => new UserStatus(value),
      },
    },
  },
};
```

How to reflect this behavior in graphql-codegen output? According to my generated types, `User.status` is of type `STATUS_ENUM`, but it should be of type `UserStatus` (cache is transforming enum to class on every read).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GraphQL Code Generator does not provide a plugin for Apollo Client Type Policies.

However, you could provide a client-side schema definition that extends the `User` type, using the `schema` configuration property: https://www.the-guild.dev/graphql/codegen/docs/config-reference/schema-field#multiple-schemas-and-client-side-schema